# Please help me convert a Linq Query to a SQL Query... Desperate

Tags: sql, linq, sql-server-2005, linqpad

Im pretty proficient in LINQ, but not in SQL.  I understand cursors are horrible and shouldn't be used.  I know SQL Syntax pretty well, but I am trying to figure out how to convert this query and update to SQL from Linq. I don't know how to go through the Foreach of SQL without using cursors and Im a bit lost on what to do next..

As you can see, I am going through an entire table of about 150,000 rows Linqpad just cannot handle the update, so I need this to be done in SQL.

Im iterating through each record in the first table, then finding a Guid in two other tables and pulling that data from those two tables and updating the original.

Can anyone help?  Thanks ALL!!!!!

```
  CS_Code.UtopiaDataContext db = new CS_Code.UtopiaDataContext();
        var getFirst = (from xx in db.Utopia_Province_Data_Captured_Gens
                        select xx);
        foreach (var item in getFirst)
        {
            var updateItem = (from xx in db.Utopia_Province_Infos
                              where xx.Province_ID == item.Province_ID
                              select xx).FirstOrDefault();
            if (updateItem != null)
            {
                item.Owner_User_ID = updateItem.User_ID;
                item.Last_Login_For_Province = updateItem.Last_Login_Province;
                item.Date_Time_User_ID_Linked = updateItem.Date_Time_Added;
                item.Added_By_User_ID = updateItem.Added_By_User_ID;
            }
            var updateItema = (from xx in db.Utopia_Province_Identifiers
                               where xx.Province_ID == item.Province_ID
                               select xx).FirstOrDefault();
            if (updateItema != null)
            {
                item.Owner_Kingdom_ID = updateItema.Owner_Kingdom_ID;
                item.Kingdom_ID = updateItema.Kingdom_ID;
                item.Province_Name = updateItema.Province_Name;
                item.Kingdom_Island = updateItema.Kingdom_Island;
                item.Kingdom_Location = updateItema.Kingdom_Location;
            }
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: Haha, Utopia, I used to play that a lot, I was the one who wrote the Utopia Simulator and Utopia Formatter version 1 and 2 :)

Comment: 2005 Sql... Anything else?

Aviad, Im the man working on UtopiaPimp...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to do an [update query](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_update.asp). First, if you can use Jon Skeet's suggestion and you're more comfortable with LINQ, then go for it. The SQL equivalent should be something like -

```
UPDATE info
SET
  gens.Owner_User_ID = item.User_ID
  gens.Last_Login_For_Province = item.Last_Login_Province
FROM
  Utopia_Province_Infos as info 
  INNER JOIN Utopia_Province_Data_Captured_Gens as gens 
  ON info.Province_ID = gens.Province_ID
```

This query *joins* two tables, making each row a "long" one that contains both tables. It proceeds to update some of the fields in each row.

You set the rest of Utopia_Province_Data_Captured_Gens's fields the same way as with User_ID.
You do the same replacing Utopia_Province_Infos with Utopia_Province_Identifiers
for the second table in your code.

**Note:** I did not take into account your usage of `FirstOrDefault`. You can set default value directly in Utopia_Province_Infos, or simply update values that have not been set (using a where clause). About the 'First' - is there more than one row with the same Province_ID in Utopia_Province_Infos? Why are you going for the first?

Comment: How do I actually go through each row of data and update each row?  Does this query actually do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should be doing a join in the first place - currently you're executing two extra queries for each row of the table, which is incredibly inefficient. Here's an example of the join:

```
var results = from xx in db.Utopia_Province_Data_Captured_Gens
              join yy in db.Utopia_Province_Infos 
                       on xx.Province_ID equals yy.Province_ID
              select new { item = xx, updateItem = yy };
foreach (var result in results)
{
    result.item.Owner_User_ID = result.updateItem.User_ID;
    result.item.Last_Login_For_Province = result.updateItem.Last_Login_Province;
    result.item.Date_Time_User_ID_Linked = result.updateItem.Date_Time_Added;
    result.item.Added_By_User_ID = result.updateItem.Added_By_User_ID;
}

// Ditto for second query
```

Note that this will update *all* items with matching `Province_ID`s rather than just the first one, but I would guess that these are the primary keys anyway, so it won't be a problem.

EDIT: I should note that Asaf's solution is a preferable in terms of efficiency. There's no point in fetching all the data back to the client when the database can do it all itself.

Comment: I can only imagine Linqpad still not being able to handle this and erroring out... 

Errors usually come with the out of memory exception...

Comment: Thanks Jon,  Even though you gave me the right answer I wish it didn't error out. Seems it kept hitting an out of memory exception because the Linqpad kept spitting out a SQL statement after each operation...

Comment: @Scott: It's odd that it's issuing a SQL statement after each operation... what kind of statement?